# Invalidate metadata for Impala through Airflow DAG

Tags: python, airflow, impala

There's daily files ingestion through AF DAG and sometimes, when files comes for example too late, client can't see data, because somebody needs manually to write invalidate metadata for tables.

I never actually done DAG coding, but i really hate to do that manually. Maybe you can give me ideas how to update that DAG ?

Comment: Please edit your question to remove the all-caps, which is generally regarded as shouting.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.